# Neurolab randomly fails to train

Tags: python, neural-network, neurolab

I set up a neural network using the neurolab package for Python 2.7 as follows (loosely based on the sample at https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newff.html). Normally, when training occurs (the line with `net.train()`), information is printed to the console, like 'The maximum number of train epochs is reached.' Training this network usually takes > 15 seconds. However, seemingly randomly and without changing the code in the slightest, the training fails: no output messages are printed to the console and classification is incorrect.

```
import neurolab as nl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(v):
    if np.linalg.norm(v) < 0.35: return 1
    elif np.linalg.norm(v) < 0.75: return 0
    else: return -1

# Create training set
print 'sampling'
x = (np.random.rand(500, 3)*2)-1
y = np.asarray([f(i) for i in x])

size = len(x)

inp = x.reshape(size,3)
tar = y.reshape(size,1)

# Create network 
print 'creating net'
net = nl.net.newff([[-1.5, 1.5]]*3, [10, 1])

# Train network
print 'training net'
net.init()
net.train(inp, tar, epochs=500, show=100, goal=0.02)

# Simulate network
print 'simulating net'
out = net.sim(inp)
out = np.asarray([int(round(i)) for i in out])

# Plot network results
print 'plotting'
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i in xrange(len(out)):
    cls = 'g'
    if out[i] == 1: cls = 'b'
    elif out[i] == -1: cls = 'r'    
    ax.scatter(x[i][0], x[i][1], x[i][2], c=cls)
    #plt.scatter(x[i][0], x[i][1], c=cls)

plt.show()
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?